# How to add style to parent element if child has not some class

Tags: html, css, less

Is it possible to add styles to parent element if child element has not selected class?

```
<style>
.parent:not(.parent > .child){
 color: red;
}
</style>
<div class="parent">Heading<span>1</span><div>
<div class="parent">Heading<span class="child">2</span><div>
```

Comment: Duplicate of: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1014861/is-there-a-css-parent-selector. You can read more details regarding why in there

Answer (score 0):

No, CSS (and LESS) work from top to bottom and you cannot traverse back up the tree. This means that a child cannot dictate the styling of a parent.

You would have to define a class or id in the parent. For example:

```
<div class="parent modified-behaviour">Heading<span class="child">2</span><div>
```

LESS compiles to CSS and thus also lacks a parent selector.

Answer (score 0):

```
With jQuery you can achieve it -
$(document).ready(function(){ 
$("div:not('.child')").parent(".parent").css("color","red");});
.parent() is for immediate parent and use .parents(), if it is a grand parent or 
great-great-grand parent.
```